# Could not load config for namespace application-yaml from Apollo, please check whether the configs are released in Apollo

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using [ctrip apollo](https://github.com/apolloconfig/apollo) to manage the application config, now I want to switch the application config from properties format to yaml format. First I added the yaml namespace called `application-yaml`, then add config in the legacy properties like this:

```
# apollo namespaces
apollo.bootstrap.enabled=true
apollo.bootstrap.eagerLoad.enabled = true
apollo.bootstrap.namespaces = application-yaml
```

after I restart the application, shows log like this:

```
[03:11:27:322] [WARN] - com.ctrip.framework.apollo.internals.DefaultConfig.getProperty(DefaultConfig.java:95) - Could not load config for namespace application-yaml from Apollo, please check whether the configs are released in Apollo! Return default value now!
```

I am confused the application still could not found the published yaml config(I checked again and again and make sure the yaml config published), am I missing something? what should I do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the namespace should end with '.yaml', you may reference the [sample](https://github.com/apolloconfig/apollo-demo-java/blob/main/spring-boot-demo/src/main/resources/application.yml) for more information.

```
apollo.bootstrap.namespaces = application-yaml.yaml
```